# Source SDK Crash at loading screen?

Tags: c++

I have followed all the instructions on how to make HL2 SDK compile under Visual Studio 2010.
But when I get to the loading screen I get this error from Visual Studio:
Unhandled exception at 0x774815ee in hl2.exe: 0x00000000: The operation completed successfully.
I have built and debugged neither make a difference.
Anyone know whats going on?

Comment: Scratch that! It just needed HL2 E2 installing -_-. Sheesh. Sorry guys.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

All you need to do is install the game thats required for the SDK you chose.
Good luck! :)